# How can I prevent URL to open in the external browser when enter used in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I am using emacs inside the terminal. In `org-mode` when the cursor on top of a hyperlink and I press enter the URL opens in the default browser.

```
* hello

[[www.google.com]]  // cursor is on the `google` key and `Ctrl+m` opens it in the browser
```

Is it possible to prevent this behavior while allowing it when there is a mouse click on the URL could open the url in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `org-return-follows-link` to `nil`. In my case, I set it to `t` and `C-h v org-return-follows-link` says:

```
org-return-follows-link is a variable defined in ‘org-keys.el’.

Its value is t
Original value was nil

Non-nil means on links RET will follow the link.
In tables, the special behavior of RET has precedence.
```

You probably set it to `t` in your init/custom file.

Comment: You are right, I had `(setq org-return-follows-link t)` in my config file, I am not sure was it set to `t`  by default

Comment: No, the default value is `nil` as the docstring states.

Comment: Hm when I removed `(setq org-return-follows-link t)` something else still set it to `t`  I am not sure which functions sets it, to be safe I have set it to nil at the end of the config file

Comment: Do you have a custom file? What does `C-h v custom-file` say?

Comment: it returns: `"~/.emacs.d/config/custom.el"` and ah its `org-return-follows-link t` in it as well . I was aonly looking into `~/emacs` file